# Add to Cart button not adding in cart Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3, addtocart

I have setup **magento 2.3.3** on server **php 7.2**.
All buttons working fine on product detail page but **Add to Cart** button not adding product in cart. Same is working fine on local pc xampp but not working on server.

I have removed all form `var/cache`, `clear cache`, `setup:static-content:deploy` etc but not fixed

Below is the url where i am getting error:

https://bigbest.in/index.php/airtel-4g-hotspot-e5573cs-609.html

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possibilities for not working add to cart :

1. Double check your secure/base secure URL's
2. Try disabling custom modules where some of them have extends funcionality for addtocart or might have syntax issue.
3. Try with `setup:up`, `setup:di:compile` and `setup:static-content:deploy` commands

Below is the steps to rectify the issue :

1. Check var/log/system.log
2. Check var/reports/latestreport file

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
1)secure/base secure URL's are fine and same.
2)Also i have done all above your advise setup:up, setup:di:compile and setup:static-content:deploy but still not work.
3)There is not generate any log/report.

Please help

Comment: @Joy try with `UPDATE core_config_data
SET value = REPLACE(value, '<old root URL or domain>', '<new root URL or domain>')
WHERE path = 'design/head/includes';` and then `rm -rf var/cache/*`